# Flutter: Updating Hmac Crypto Package

Tags: node.js, flutter, dart, cryptography

I am trying to reproduce a scenario with crypto package in dart. The scenario in nodejs is something like this with the nodejs cryto package as well -

**nodejs**

```
const crypto = require('crypto')

var timeStamp = Math.floor(Date.now());

key = "";
secret = ""

body = {
    "timestamp": timeStamp
}

const payload = new Buffer(JSON.stringify(body)).toString();

const signature = crypto.createHmac('sha256', secret).update(payload).digest('hex')
```

I cannot find out the implementation of **update** method (nodejs example last line) in dart.
So far, I can only obtain an HMAC object using one dataset.

**My Dart Code**

```
int timeStamp = DateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch;

    Map<String, dynamic> body = {
      "timestamp": timeStamp,
    };

    String payload = jsonEncode(body);

    var key = utf8.encode(secret);
    var bytes = utf8.encode(payload);

    Hmac hmacShaFirst = Hmac(sha256, key);
    var signature = hmacShaFirst.convert(bytes);

    print("HMAC digest as bytes: ${signature.bytes}");
    print("HMAC digest as hex string: $signature");
```

Thanks!

Comment: Not reproducible. Both codes give the same result for the same content of `timeStamp` and `secret`. Pls post a concrete example. Two notes: On NodeJS side, `Math.floor()` should actually be redundant because [`Date.now()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now) returns the number in milliseconds, which is an integer. On Dart side, `timeStamp` is currently given in _microseconds_, which therefore needs to be changed to [`DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.4/dart-core/DateTime/millisecondsSinceEpoch.html).

Comment: Thanks, nodejs is not my concern I only added it from the docs of this API so answerers can relate to what I am trying to do. Secondly, microseconds was a type, thanks for the correction.
I'll try to summarise the problem - the nodejs code first creates an HMAC with the key and that uses UPDATE method on it to create another HMAC using json data (I suppose). On dart side, I am only able to create one HMAC and can't find the counterpart of the UPDATE method on dart's side.

Comment: In the NodeJS code, an HMAC object is created with `crypto.createHmac()`. The data is passed with `hmac.update()` and the HMAC value is returned with `hmac.digest()`. In the Dart code, `Hmac()` also creates the HMAC object. With `Hmac.convert()` the data is passed **and** the HMAC value is returned, i.e. `convert()` combines the functionalities of `update()` and `digest()`. The NodeJS construct however, has the advantage that `update()` can be called several times. Both codes give the same result on my machine. If this is different for you, you should post sample data.

Comment: thanks for your help, you are right. I wrongly assumed that there has to be a counterpart to the update() function while convert() does all the work. You may want to add an answer as an answer if you feel it necessary.